# Why is this rotation "incorrect"?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I've been trying to use the following formula for the rotation of a point around the origin:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, I'm trying to apply this formula to the coordinate $(5,3)$ and rotating it $90$ degrees clockwise, and I ended up with the following result:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{90} & -\sin{90} \\
\sin{90} & \cos{90}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix} 
\\
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix} 
\\
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0(5) -1(3) \\
1(5) + 0(3)
\end{bmatrix} \\
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\ 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I ended up with the rotated coordinates $(-3,5)$. Unfortunately, this was wrong. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how I can do it correctly? I tried this method on other coordinate points, and all of them were wrong as well.

Comment: It is correctly rotating by a quarter turn counterclockwise. What answer were you expecting?

Comment: @Adriano Oh wow, I feel really stupid. I was supposed to be rotating clockwise.

Comment: For clockwise, move the minus sign to the other $\sin$ in the matrix, I think. (It's the result of replacing $\theta$ with $-\theta$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems right to me. Ah, maybe you're thinking of a clockwise rotation. That matrix gives a counterclockwise rotation through an angle $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, or for anyone who happens to stumble upon this question looking for help, here's the two *proper* equations for rotation, where $\theta$ is a positive number in the range $0\rightarrow360$, and $x$ and $y$ are the $x$ and $y$ values for your point.

**Clockwise**

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta} \\
-\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Counterclockwise**

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Alternatively, you can just use positive *and* negative rotation values for $\theta$ as well.

Answer (score -1):

It is correct. What makes one think that it is wrong? You mean the convention that CCW is positive?

EDIT1:

What I meant is with Clockwise rotation I obtain $(-3,5)$ by matrix multiplication and Counterclockwise rotation gives  $(3,-5)$ for a diametrically opposite point. So only association with sign convention of rotation could be the source of error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I edited it, that was too short, right?